# Pars and extract urls inside an html web content without using BeautifulSoup or urlib libraries

Tags: python, html, arrays, string, html-parsing

I am new in python and I am so sorry if my question is very basic. In my program, I need to pars an html web page and extract all of the links inside that. Assume my web page content is such as below:

```
<html><head><title>Fakebook</title><style TYPE="text/css"><!--
#pagelist li { display: inline; padding-right: 10px; }
--></style></head><body><h1>testwebapp</h1><p><a href="/testwebapp/">Home</a></p><hr/><h1>Welcome to testwebapp</h1><p>Random URLs!</p><ul><li><a href="/testwebapp/847945358/">Rennie Tach</a></li><li><a href="/testwebapp/848854776/">Pid Ko</a></li><li><a href="/testwebapp/850558104/">Ler She</a></li><li><a href="/testwebapp/851635068/">iti Sar</a></li><li><a </ul>
<p>Page 1 of 2
<ul id="pagelist"><li>
1 

</li><li><a href="/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/">2</a></li><li><a href="/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/">next</a></li><li><a href="/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/">last</a></li></ul></p>
</body></html>
```

Now, I need to pars this web content and extract all of the links inside that. In another words, I need below content to be extracted from the web page:

```
/testwebapp/847945358/
/testwebapp/848854776/
/testwebapp/850558104/
/testwebapp/851635068/
/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/
/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/
/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/
```

I searched so much about parsing web pages using python such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234614/parsing-web-page-in-python-using-beautiful-soup), [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/) or [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using-regular-expressions-urllib/), but many of them have used libraries such as urlib or urlib2 or BeautifulSoup and request which I can not use these libraries in my program. Because my application will run on a machine that these libraries have not been installed on that. So I need to parse my web content manually. My idea was that, I save my web page content in a string and then I convert the string((separated by space)) to an array of string and then check each item of my array and if it has `/testwebapp/` or `fri` keyword, save that in an array. But when I am using below command for converting the string contain my web page content to an array, I got this error:

```
arrayofwords_fromwebpage = (webcontent_saved_in_a_string).split(" ")
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

IS there any quick and efficient way for parsing and extracting this links inside an html web page without using any library such as urlib, urlib2 or BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that you need is to found all url use only Python, this function will help you:

```
def search(html):
    HREF = 'a href="'
    res = []
    s, e = 0, 0
    while True:
        s = html.find(HREF, e)
        if s == -1:
            break
        e = html.find('">', s)
        res.append(html[s+len(HREF):e])

    return res
```

Comment: This is perfect @AndMar.tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use something from the standard library, namely HTMLParser.

I subclass it for your purpose by watching for 'a' tags. When the parser encounters one it looks for the 'href' attribute and, if it's present, it prints its value.

To execute it, I instantiate the subclass, then give its `feed` method the HTML that you presented in your question.

You can see the results at the end of this answer.

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>> class SharoozHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         if tag == 'a':
...             attrs = {k: v for (k, v) in attrs}
...             if 'href' in attrs:
...                 print (attrs['href'])
...                 
>>> parser = SharoozHTMLParser()
>>> parser.feed(open('temp.htm').read())
/testwebapp/
/testwebapp/847945358/
/testwebapp/848854776/
/testwebapp/850558104/
/testwebapp/851635068/
/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/
/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/
/testwebapp/570508160/fri/2/
```

Comment: Thank you @Bill Bell, It will works me definitely, I will use that.

Comment: Sorry, I take it back. Didn't notice you'd already accepted another answer.